# how to reset DNS settings to the defaults?

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

while I'm learning the DNS, I have installed too many apps such as BIND and DNSmasq and made some changes to /etc/resolve.conf

and now I would like to reset the DNS settings to defaults? I have removed DNSmasq and the things I remember but is there's someway to reset the DNS settings to defaults rather than reinstall the system?

Comment: What *buntu version are you using? Are you using systemd-resolved or not?

Comment: In tags you see ubuntu 18.04 is tagged, yes I have systemd-resolved enabled and running

Answer (score 16):

First, your /etc/systemd/resolved.conf should look like:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

Then run: `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf && sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

And check your systemd-resolved is enabled with: `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` and if not then enable it: `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` and start: `systemctl start systemd-resolved.service`

Seems, that's all.

Comment: Thank you, I recently removed Pihole from a server and was running into DNS issues.  With all the changes made to Ubuntu networking, I had a hard time figuring out which method worked.  This set things back to normal.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Chrome still gives DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG. status systemd-resolved.service gives `another process is listening on tcp socker 127.0.0.53:53 ` `turning off local DNS stub support`