# no internet after yesterday's upgrade

Tags: networking, upgrade, internet

Yesterday I ran updates, which took quite a long time, and since then the internet is not working on my laptop. the wifi icon shows, and says it has a good connection, and if i connect with ethernet cable it all shows as if it is connecting. however nothing is working - i cannot connect to any websites, download email or use other online apps such as slack.
i have recently installed cyberghost, so now i'm trying to uninstall that in case it's what's causing the problem - however it won't uninstall so am now on live chat with their support people.
i looked at the upgrade log from yesterday but really have no idea what of the many packages might be the problem :(

[image]

SOLVED - but i can't say excactly how ... i tried to follow the suggestion of @user535733 to boot from the previous kernel. i shutdown then pressed the start button and held the shift key down. this did not bring me to the grub menu, the laptop fired up as normal - and with internet!!
i tried all of the suggestions offered and did plenty of restarts along the way. could restarting with the shift key down have solved it?
thank you all very much for your helpful and fast responses.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and: `ls-al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: i am trying to do this but having multiple problems trying to get image from phone to a different laptop where internet is working :/

Comment: omg just had a nightmare of nothing working - bluetooth, email, nothing sending or receiving ... it seems there are more gremlins in the system than just in my linux laptop :(  we have to back away from the keyboard to calm down! any help or suggestions much appreciated. i have already searched a lot and tried many things such as resetting tcp/ip and many restarts, nothing has made a difference :(

Comment: Providing basic details such as what OS/release you're using is always a good start.  As we don't know what release you're using, we can't look up what *updates* you are talking about; but also knowing how often you upgrade is useful too (hourly? daily? weekly? etc)

Comment: It is not ls-al as I mistakenly typed. Sorry for my mis-step. Please try: `ls  -al  /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: ls -al /etc/resolv.conf returned this: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22 Dez 26 21:52 /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: sorry for incomplete information (it's been a bit stressful). i'm running ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. the software updater is set to automatically check for security updates daily, and other updates weekly. but yesterday i did a manual update because firefox would not play a video and the error message told me i needed to update. i could not find a way to update just firefox, as the browser was telling me it was up to date, so i ran the updater. this took about an hour which really surprised me as normally the updates are quite fast.

Comment: i had a look via the terminal at what had updated & could see plenty of things that i don't think can have affected the network but lots of things that i have no idea what they are, so difficult to guess what might need to be rolled back. however, from doing further research, it seems that a lot of linux users have similar problems of network disconnection when or after using a VPN so i think the problem is connected to cyberghost. they sent instructions for uninstalling it, but i get the same errors as before  so am unable to uninstall it ... thank you in advance for any further suggestions!

Comment: "*firefox would not play a video and the error message told me i needed to update*" that's suspicious. "*I ran updates, which took quite a long time*" is also very suspicious. Regardless of your DNS problem, your system may have other, older, underlying problems.

Comment: Try booting Ubuntu using the previous kernel. You do this from grub. If you have dual boot, grub is visible when the computer starts. If not, hold down the Shift key after pressing the power button to start the computer. Once you see the grub menu, go to the advanced option. There you will see the current kernel at the top followed by the current kernel in safe mode. The third item should be the previous kernel. Select that using the Down arrow. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1447400/edit) and add if it restores internet or not.

Comment: In general, do not add new information in comments. Always update your question. Once you have done that notify the person who asked for it by a new comment starting with `@the-username-of-the-person-who-asked-for-it`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be a Domain Name System (DNS) problem.

DNS is the phone directory of the internet. Your computer deals with numbers (e.g. 8.8.8.8) but you usually use hostnames (dns.google -> 8.8.8.8)

As you are able to ping a IP address sucessfully but can't connect to internet sites using your browser, the first thing to look at is whether you need to adjust your DNS settings.

Try [resetting your DNS settings to the default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106659/how-to-reset-dns-settings-to-the-defaults).

Comment: thanks mark, i tried this & i don't know what it actually did but when i did the step for checking that systemd-resolved is enabled, it says  that it is enabled. but the internet still does not work. i did a restart and still nothing.